# MongoDB flashcards

Tags: mongodb, atlas

Ok, so I've been trying to connect mongoDB Atlas to VS code to create a flashcard app.  I have three different files, the server.js, client.js and html file.  I am successfully able to connect to the database on Atlas and when I go to localhost:3000/ it only shows an empty array.  What I'm trying to do is use the input fields from the html file so that they are stored in the collection.

```
App.js
onst form = document.getElementById('flashcard-form');
const frontInput = document.getElementById('front-input');
const backInput = document.getElementById('back-input');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const question = frontInput.value;
    const answer = backInput.value;

    const flashcard = { question, answer };

    fetch('/flashcards', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(flashcard),
    })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('Flashcard created:', data);
            // Handle success, e.g., display a success message
            // Reset the input fields
        frontInput.value = '';
        backInput.value = '';
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error creating flashcard:', error);
            // Handle error, e.g., display an error message
        });
});
```

```
server.js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const dbUri = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.pfvqylq.mongodb.net/";

mongoose.connect(dbUri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB Atlas');
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error connecting to MongoDB Atlas', error);
  });

const flashcardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  question: String,
  answer: String,
});

const Flashcard = mongoose.model('Flashcard', flashcardSchema);

// Create a new flashcard
app.post('/flashcards', (req, res) => {
  const { question, answer } = req.body;

  const flashcard = new Flashcard({ question, answer });
  flashcard.save()
    .then(() => {
      res.status(201).json(flashcard);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred' });
    });
});

// Get all flashcards
app.get('/flashcards', (req, res) => {
  Flashcard.find()
    .then((flashcards) => {
      res.json(flashcards);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred' });
    });
});

// Delete a flashcard
app.delete('/flashcards/:id', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;

  Flashcard.findByIdAndDelete(id)
    .then(() => {
      res.sendStatus(204);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred' });
    });
});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Flashcard App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="flashcard-container">
      <div id="flashcard-template" class="flashcard card mb-3">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="front card-title"></h3>
          <p class="back card-text"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <form id="flashcard-form" class="mt-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text" id="front-input" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Front of the flashcard" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text" id="back-input" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Back of the flashcard" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Flashcard</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Trying to store information which is submitted through input fields from html file so that they appear in my MongoDB Atlas collections.